# WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE pemission pop up not display after upgrading to tragetsk 33 and compile sdk 33 in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions

WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE pemission pop up not display after upgrading to tragetsk 33 and compile sdk 33 in kotlin.
With same code, permission Pop up is showing in android 10 ph.
But not showing in android 13 ph. the checking grant result for WRITE_EXTERNAL _STORAGE permission is -1 which is not granted.

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/q/72948052/18858169

Comment: @BhavinSolanki , thanks for the suggestion. issue was resolved by using the READ_MEDIA_IMAGES permission instead of WRITE_EXTERNAL _STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL _STORAGE

Answer (score 0):

For android versions which less than API 29 **(android 10)**

you need to request `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` .

otherwise it's already granted because of ScopedStorage that released at android 11.

you can still use `WRITE_EXTERNAL _STORAGE` in android 10 if you add **`requestLegacyStorage = true`** to your manifest, but thats will not work for greater versions .

you should read about ScopedStorage: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage

and update your manifest to:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. my issue was resolved by using the READ_MEDIA_IMAGES permission instead of WRITE_EXTERNAL _STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL _STORAGE . credit to : stackoverflow.com/q/72948052/18858169