# Android 13 - How to request WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions, runtime-permissions, android-13

I am targeting my Android app for Android 13 (API 33)

The WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission seems to be working fine below API 33 i.e. Android 12 and less but the runtime permission popup for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE won't appear when running the app on Android 13.

My Android app creates one keystore file in app's private storage.

The behaviour changes for Android 13 mention this:

> If your app targets Android 13, you must request one or more new
> permissions instead of the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

The new permissions are:

- Images and photos: READ_MEDIA_IMAGES
- Videos: READ_MEDIA_VIDEO Audio
- Audio files: READ_MEDIA_AUDIO

I didn't find any information about this in the official documentation.
The documentation is focusing on media files only without any word about other file types.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions

Comment: `My Android app creates one keystore file in app's private storage.` For that not any permission is needed.

Comment: And better read your link: `If your app targets Android 13 or higher and needs to access media files that other apps have created,` So if you want to create files on external storage you still should request write external storage permission. I dont know why there is no user interaction more. But more important: do you get write access for external storage (that is not app private)?

Comment: The same. So my app got a huge bug because the scenario with create file checks permission and user can't go to next step

Comment: Check this answer as it has some good points: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73630987/8929068

Answer (score 79):

TLDR: You don't.

From Google's [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage):

"If your app targets Android 11, both the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission and the WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE privileged permission no longer provide any additional access."

So in effect, if you were to request WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE on Android 11 or later, you would be requesting nothing. This is the whole point of Android's migration to scoped storage, which effectively prevents apps from reading or writing to the storage directories of other apps UNLESS they are accessing specific file types (e.g. media, using the permissions you mentioned) or are granted special file manager permissions by Google themselves. For more insight into scoped storage, see this well written [article](https://www.androidcentral.com/what-scoped-storage), but TLDR security and leftover files from app uninstalls were the big reasons Google did this.

So if you really want to write files, either make sure you're only writing to your app's [designated storage directories](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#app-specific-external), in which case you won't need any permissions at all, or if you really need to write to a directory your app doesn't own get that file manager permission from Google ([how to get that permission](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#all-files-access))

Comment: Just to add, if you try to check or request the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE on Android 13+, it will always return false. So you'll have to skip the permission check/request completely on Android 13+.

Comment: @HishamHijjawi  I checked `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission` with READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. On A12 it returned true (at least after I called `requestPermissions` and accepted the storage permission request). But it returned false on A13 and there was no permission request popup for storage at all, when I called `requestPermissions` . I'm also using `requestLegacyExternalStorage`, but that should not affect this behavior because `requestLegacyExternalStorage` should be ignored completely since A11 versions.

Comment: i need to create file 
but i got errro  EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: But how about Media Store? Can it help to save a pdf file into the Downloads directory?

Answer (score 4):

You can find documentation for accessing non-media files at [Android official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files) or "[How to Save a File in Shared Storage Location in Android 13](https://medium.com/@vivekvashistha/how-to-save-a-file-in-shared-storage-location-in-android-13-c1e4fdf3d2cb)". From Android 10 onwards, if you want to write a file which is intended to be accessible directly by other apps (such as File manager) or user, then you have to write it onto Shared Storage location. This has to be done in 3 steps:

**Step 1:** Launch System Picker to choose the destination by the user.

```
private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> launcher; // Initialise this object in Activity.onCreate()
private Uri baseDocumentTreeUri;
public void launchBaseDirectoryPicker() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
        launcher.launch(intent);
 }
```

**Step 2:** Receive the chosen destination as Uri returned by System Picker in onActivityResult(). Here, you can optionally persist the permissions and Uri for future use.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
        if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            baseDocumentTreeUri = Objects.requireNonNull(result.getData()).getData();
            final int takeFlags = (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

            // take persistable Uri Permission for future use
            context.getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(result.getData().getData(), takeFlags);
            SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("com.example.fileutility", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            preferences.edit().putString("filestorageuri", result.getData().getData().toString()).apply();
        } else {
            Log.e("FileUtility", "Some Error Occurred : " + result);
        }
}
```

**Step 3:** Write content into a file.

```
public void writeFile(String fileName, String content)  {
        try {
            DocumentFile directory = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, baseDocumentTreeUri);
            DocumentFile file = directory.createFile("text/*", fileName);
            ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(file.getUri(), "w");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
            fos.write(content.getBytes());
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I Android 13 and above WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is granted by default and you not have to grant it by code.
e.g

```
           if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU){
            saveImage();
        }else {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            } else {
                
                saveImage();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is worked for me for react native

```
  // other imports
 import DeviceInfo from "react-native-device-info"

  // other states
  const [apiLevel, setAPILevel] = useState(null);

  //update your state variable
  useEffect(()=>{
  const getDeviceInfo = async()=>{
    const apiLevel = DeviceInfo.getSystemVersion();
    setAPILevel(apiLevel);
    console.log(" ~ file: app.tsx:115 ~ getDeviceInfo ~ apiLevel:", 
    apiLevel)
      
   }
  getDeviceInfo();
 },[])


if (Platform.OS === "android" && apiLevel < 13) {
        console.log(" ~ file: SingleCategoryScreen.tsx:327 ~ 
   downloadAllLectureVideos ~ Platform.OS:", Platform.OS)
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
          PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        )
        if (granted !== PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
          console.log("Permission denied. Cannot download videos.");
          setIsDownloading(false)
          return
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ( READ_MEDIA_IMAGES ) instead of ( WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ) If you are using sdk 33.

Comment: But READ is READ, will that grant WRITE as well? I doubt.

Comment: If you required WRITE and READ both then only use WRITE because WRITE will automatically add READ but if you only required READ then it is good to use READ only.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to request permission in android 13>
You have to control the version and make the actions

Answer (score 0):

TO CHECK  WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE For Android API 31 and aove

```
    public static boolean isGrantedPermissionWRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE(Activity activity) {
        int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if( version <= 32 ) {
            boolean isAllowPermissionApi28 = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ;
            Log.i("general_em","isGrantedPermissionWRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE() - isAllowPermissionApi28: " + isAllowPermissionApi28);
            return  isAllowPermissionApi28;
        } else {
            boolean isAllowPermissionApi33 = Environment.isExternalStorageManager();
            Log.i("general_em","isGrantedPermissionWRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE() - isAllowPermissionApi33: " + isAllowPermissionApi33);
            return isAllowPermissionApi33;
        }
    }
```