# Xamarin.Android MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync does not work in Android 13

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-13, xamarin-essentials

I am using the Xamarin.Essentials MediaPicker for capturing images in my app.
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/essentials/media-picker?tabs=android

just like `var photo = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();`

For Android < 13 I am asking for permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

and everything works fine.

Since those permission do not work for Android 13, I am asking for

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
```

(see [Android 13 - How to request WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73620790/android-13-how-to-request-write-external-storage))

the problem is, that the **Xamarin.Essentials.MediaPicker still misses the StorageWritePermission** when trying to take a photo. But I can't ask for those in Android 13.

[image]

Any ideas how to make it work for Android 13?

**Info**:

- Uploading an image works fine (`MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync`)
- Device tested: Samsung Galaxy Tab 7 FE Android 13
- Device tested: Google Pixle 7 Android 13
- Bug thread https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/2041

**Update:**

- Pull request https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/pull/2065 which could fix this problem

Comment: Who told you that it uses or needs those permissions? They are not needed.

Comment: Any answers for this, I have the same issue.

Comment: @blackapps the Exception Handler told me that, because the app crashes (see the screenshot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in Xamarin.Essentials Nuget Update **1.7.5**

No problem on my Android 13 devices after updating the NugetPackage

[image]

Comment: added that, unfortunately still crashing

Comment: still crashing because of permission exception? My Samsung Tab also Crashes while taking pictures (sometimes), but not because the error in this thread

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

In Android 13, the method `MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync()` can not be used due to the permission. You can check the issue thread [Storage permissions Android 13 api 33](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/2041) for more information.

**The code below works for versions prior to Android 13**

I created a demo on my side and it worked well, you can refer to this.
I am using the permissions below.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

 <queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Here is the code in .cs file.

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
        {
            public string PhotoPath { get; set; } = null;
            public MainPage()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
    
            private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                var file = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();
                await LoadPhotoAsync(file);
                if (file == null)
                    return;
                async Task LoadPhotoAsync(FileResult photo)
                {
                    // canceled
                    if (photo == null)
                    {
                        PhotoPath = null;
                        return;
                    }
                    // save the file into local storage
                    var newFile = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, photo.FileName);
                    using (var stream = await photo.OpenReadAsync())
                    using (var newStream = File.OpenWrite(newFile))
                        await stream.CopyToAsync(newStream);
                    PhotoPath = newFile;
                    img.Source = PhotoPath;//Show on the front page
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is the code in xaml

```
<StackLayout>
    <Button Text="button" Clicked="Button_Clicked"></Button>
    <Image x:Name="img" ></Image>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: I tested the `MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync()` , you need to add the `<queries>
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
  </intent>
</queries>` in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: this does not work on my Samsung Tab 7 FE Android 13. I even cannot ask for the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. There won't come the popup to grant the permission

Comment: ..... but those permission should not be needed in Android 13, but the CapterPhotoAsync still asks for them

Comment: This seems an issue on the android 13 you can check the issue thread [Storage permissions Android 13 api 33](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/2041).

Answer (score 0):

Acording with release notes, version 1.8.0 should work with Android 13

"Xamarin.Essentials now is built against Android 13.0 SDK."

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/xamarin/essentials/release-notes/1.8

Regards