# Photo select from storage does not work on Android 13 from Xamarin Forms application

Tags: android, forms, xamarin

We have an requirement where we need to select images from android storage, so in Xamarin Forms application we have added following code,

```
public async Task<bool> CheckAndRequestStoragePermission()
    {
        PermissionStatus status = PermissionStatus.Unknown;

        bool isPermissionChecked = false;

        Version version = DeviceInfo.Version;

        if (DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android)
        {
            if (version.Major >= 12)
            {
                isPermissionChecked = true;

                status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Photos>();

                if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.Photos>();
                }
            }
        }

        if (isPermissionChecked == false)
        {
            status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();

            if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();
            }
        }

        return status == PermissionStatus.Granted;
    }

    private async void OnChooseImageButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            await CheckAndRequestStoragePermission();

            var photo = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync();
            if (photo != null)
            {
                imagePathList.Add(photo.FullPath);
                selectedImages.Add(new SelectedImage { ImagePath = photo.FullPath });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error picking image: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
```

Also added required permissions in Android manifest file as,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
```

But on Android device, application does not ask for the permissions and "status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();" auto returns with Denied permission. Also it throws an exception as following line,

```
var photo = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync();
```

and exception is about StorageRead permission.

Please guide us how to make it work on Android version 13 devices.

Comment: What is the value of `photo.FullPath` ? Tell exact full path please.

Comment: You should not ask that READ an WRITE permission on Androis 13+ devices.

Comment: Does it help? [Xamarin.Android MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync does not work in Android 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74983641/xamarin-android-mediapicker-capturephotoasync-does-not-work-in-android-13)

Answer (score 0):

If your app targets Android **13** or higher and needs to access media files that other apps have created, you must request one or more of the following granular media permissions instead of the **READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permission:

- Images and photos | READ_MEDIA_IMAGES
- Videos           | READ_MEDIA_VIDEO
- Audio files       | READ_MEDIA_AUDIO

Unfortunately .NET Maui does not contain Permissions about the three above, so you have to write platform specific code :

```
 try
 {
     if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.ReadMediaImages) != Permission.Granted)
     {
         ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new[] { Manifest.Permission.ReadMediaImages }, 0);
     }
 }
 catch (Exception exception)
 {
     Console.WriteLine($"Error at requesting Permissions with error message : {exception.Message}");

 }
```

*OR*

Create a class called **ReadMediaImagesPermissions** that inheritances the base class : **Permissions.BasePlatformPermission** :

```
public class ReadMediaImagesPermissions: Permissions.BasePlatformPermission
{
    public override (string androidPermission, bool isRuntime)[] RequiredPermissions => new List<(string androidPermission, bool isRuntime)>
    {
        (Android.Manifest.Permission.ReadMediaImages, true),
    }.ToArray();
}
```

and call it like this :

```
var status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<ReadMediaImagesPermissions>();
```

Comment: `If your app targets Android 13 or higher ` You mean: `If your app runs on a device with Android 13 or higher ..`.

Comment: Based on this doc : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions, I just transfer the guidelines from the official documentation of android.

Comment: I will not read that. But just think about this:  your app targets 13 but runs on a device with Android 10. Then it does not make sense to request READ_MEDIA_IMAGES as that is for Android 13+ devices. Running on 12- your app will need READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: Yes, you are right about that!