# Which File picker to use for working with getFilesDir()?

Tags: java, android

My app uses deprecated file picker com.adityak:browsemyfiles for accessing app-specific files for saving and loading those files into the app.
With Android 13 I ran into the problem because this feature stopped working since there WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions are no longer supported.
I would like to access the same folder with getFilesDir() where users have their files.
What is the best way to allow users to save and load files from this location?

Comment: "With Android 13 I ran into the problem because this feature stopped working since there WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions are no longer supported" -- you do not need those permissions for `getFilesDir()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if i understand your question correctly or not but here is my opinion...

As [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) mentioned about **getFilesDir()** you **don't need** any specific permission it's your own app private directory.

And about the permissions [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73620790/android-13-how-to-request-write-external-storage) may help you for **deprecated** permissions (in short just **use** **MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** for full Access).

Here is how you can use it in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

And request in activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION,
            Uri.parse("package:" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()));
startActivity(intent);
```

If by any chance you want to access **/Android/data/** it's a little tricky... you can't get full directory access and should get user permission for each and every file in that path, that **may not be pleasant** for user.

Hope this may answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I need only a sub folder in the getFilesDir() directory, so it seems to solve my issue.