# How to use READ_MEDIA_IMAGES instead of READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE after Android 13 upgrade?

Tags: android, react-native

I upgraded my react-native project to Android 13, now camera-roll is not asking for permission, as it was using before READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, and now we have granular permission for READ_MEDIA_IMAGES, READ_MEDIA_AUDIO and READ_MEDIA_VIDEO. I am new to react-native and mobile development, need some help understanding here, that just adding these permissions to the Manifest file won't help, do I also need to specify that we need to ask for READ_MEDIA_IMAGES permission to make it start asking for permission again? I have upgraded the libraries required here like react-native-permissions, camera-roll library and react-native-image-crop as these all were being used and they have now added the granular permissions to their libraries.

I am using react-native-image-crop-picker to access the image picker here,

Answer (score 0):

You don't need permission from android 10 and onwards. You just need to ask storage related permissions for SDK less than android 10.
A detailed answer already given.

[ANDROID 13 PERMISSION](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73630987/8083050)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33568936)