# Storage Permission in Android 13 - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-permissions

I'm making the use of read and write permission for accessing external storage and for getting the permission, I'm using the permission handler package

AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

For getting the permission from user

```dart
var status = await Permission.storage.request();
if (status.isGranted) {
  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Home())
  );
} else if (status.isPermanentlyDenied) {
  openAppSettings();
}
```

The above permissions and code working perfectly for android versions till 12 but when it comes to android version 13, it is not working up, it just opens up the app setting instead of asking the permission

Comment: This happens because the permission is already released, there was a change in this permission in relation to sdk 33, as [described here](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/issues/885) and [here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72948052/android-13-read-external-storage-permission-still-usable).

Comment: So you are suggesting that I don't need to ask for the storage permission in android versions which are greater than 12? What I'm doing is getting the video url from API and saving it to the gallery, do I need permission for that? @Chance

Comment: Pretty strange you are still asking as you know already that permissions are given implicit. And why not just test it? And you did not tell which storage location you are after.

Comment: Just tested it! No need to ask permission in android version 13 :) @blackapps

Comment: You should check the permission yes, but in the permission handler there is a bug where it checks the permission in sdk 33 with denied status, as [described in their issue](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/issues/885).

Answer (score 13):

***For Android 13 or higher***

**Menifest Permissions**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO"/>
```

**permission_handler (request)**

```
await Permission.photos.request();
```

Comment: Not working, used permission_handler: ^8.1.6

Comment: how can we read pdf files?

Comment: @Usama   what should be the permission for accessing files like pdf,excel,ppt,audio files ??

Comment: Flutter does not need permission for pdf or a package to work. Remove permission handler for storage and it will work just fine because in API 33 no such permission exist so it will always return empty.

Answer (score 11):

**setp 1**

add permission android manifest

```xml
<!-- Required only if your app targets Android 13 or higher. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
     android:maxSdkVersion="33" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" 
       android:maxSdkVersion="33"  />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO"/>
```

**setp 2**

```dart
var status = await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();
if (status.isGranted) {
  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Home())
  );
} else if (status.isPermanentlyDenied) {
  openAppSettings();
}
```

[image]

Comment: how do we specify the image to be used in the permission dialog ?

Comment: Thanks -  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
 android:maxSdkVersion="33" />` - I'm just adding `android:maxSdkVersion="33"` and it's working fine for me.

Comment: @DevPankajPatel   maxSdkVersion="33" or maxSdkVersion="32"  ???

Comment: @mohammed shamseerpv   maxSdkVersion="33" or maxSdkVersion="32" ???

Comment: @mohammed shamseerpv what should be the permission for accessing files like pdf,excel,ppt,audio files ??

Comment: @KJEjava48 maxSdkVersion="32"  worked for me after updating the Android update storage requestion permission policy. Before updating policy 33 is working fine.

Answer (score 6):

If you use targetSdk version 33 then use following code.

```dart
bool permissionStatus;
final deviceInfo = await DeviceInfoPlugin().androidInfo;
    
if (deviceInfo.version.sdkInt > 32) {
    permissionStatus = await Permission.photos.request().isGranted;
} else {
    permissionStatus = await Permission.storage.request().isGranted;
}
```

use this permission manifest file:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
```

Comment: what should be the permission for accessing files like pdf,excel,ppt,audio files ??

Answer (score 2):

i found the way for any android version after lots of search and testing

**Breaking Change after android 13 was released**

Requesting "storage" permissions always returns "denied" on Android 13+. What can I do? #
On Android, the Permission.storage permission is linked to the Android READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions. Starting from Android 10 (API 29) the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions have been marked deprecated and have been fully removed/disabled since Android 13 (API 33).

If your application needs access to media files Google recommends using the READ_MEDIA_IMAGES, READ_MEDIA_VIDEOS, or READ_MEDIA_AUDIO permissions instead. These can be requested using the Permission.photos, Permission.videos, and Permission.audio respectively. To request these permissions make sure the compileSdkVersion in the android/app/build.gradle file is set to 33.

If your application needs access to Android's file system, it is possible to request the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission (using Permission.manageExternalStorage). As of Android 11 (API 30), the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is considered a high-risk or sensitive permission. Therefore it is required to declare the use of these permissions if you intend to release the application via the Google Play Store. [More...](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler)

Add following in your manifest file:

```
    <!-- for below android 13-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- for above android 13-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />

    <!-- InternetPermission -->
```

Also add    **android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"**   line in  tab Like

```
        <application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" // add here
        android:label="iFlutter"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"
    >
```

**Note**

Here we manage request in manifest for above android version 13 and below 13
but still question is how to identified and user this permission for all devices (for any android version)

Here we used  [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler)  and  [device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus)  with latest version

Now i make method this will handle for any android version for storage permission

```
Future<bool> storagePermission() async {
  final DeviceInfoPlugin info = DeviceInfoPlugin(); // import 'package:device_info_plus/device_info_plus.dart';
  final AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await info.androidInfo;
  debugPrint('releaseVersion : ${androidInfo.version.release}');
  final int androidVersion = int.parse(androidInfo.version.release);
  bool havePermission = false;

  if (androidVersion >= 13) {
    final request = await [
      Permission.videos,
      Permission.photos,
      //..... as needed
    ].request(); //import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

    havePermission = request.values.every((status) => status == PermissionStatus.granted);
  } else {
    final status = await Permission.storage.request();
    havePermission = status.isGranted;
  }

  if (!havePermission) {
    // if no permission then open app-setting
    await openAppSettings();
  }

  return havePermission;
}
```

**How to Use**

```
         // Your button
         onPressed: () async {
            final permission = await storagePermission();
            debugPrint('permission : $permission');
          },
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in AndroidMenifest.xml for permission,

```
<!--for android 13 and above-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" /> <!-- For Images-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEOS" /> <!-- For video-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" /> <!-- For Audio-->

<!-- for below android 13-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Add this dependencies in pubspec.yaml

```
device_info_plus: ^version
```

Add this snippet of code :

```
Future<void> _getStoragePermission() async {
    DeviceInfoPlugin plugin = DeviceInfoPlugin();
    AndroidDeviceInfo android = await plugin.androidInfo;
       if (android.version.sdkInt < 33) {
          if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
             setState(() {
               permissionGranted = true;
             });
          } else if (await Permission.storage.request().isPermanentlyDenied) {
             await openAppSettings();
          } else if (await Permission.audio.request().isDenied) {
             setState(() {
               permissionGranted = false;
             });
          }
        } else {
           if (await Permission.photos.request().isGranted) {
                setState(() {
                   permissionGranted = true;
                });
           } else if (await Permission.photos.request().isPermanentlyDenied) {
               await openAppSettings();
           } else if (await Permission.photos.request().isDenied) {
               setState(() {
                   permissionGranted = false;
               });
         }
      }
}
```

Happy Codding!

Comment: what should be the permission for accessing files like pdf,excel,ppt,audio files ??

Comment: You can use remove permission for audio, or simple use above same code.
It may work!

Comment: remove for audio?? are u sure ?? or is for record instead of audio??

Comment: As far as your file concern, it is sufficient to provide storage permission for accessing files like pdf, excel, ppt and audio. if you want to record audio(using microphone) then you have to ask permission for audio.

Comment: So u r saying storage permission will work for accessing files like pdf, excel, ppt and audio in android.version.sdkInt > 32 ???

Comment: Hi @KJEjava48, Storage permission will work below 33 sdk, and for 33 and above this please have a look in https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13

Answer (score 0):

In a recent developer release, there is no need to ask for permission in case of files, so you can directly use [FilePicker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) to access storage, But you need to specify the follwoing permissions in the Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

And the permission handler_package is buggy for this, which always return denied as the status