# Storage Permission in Android 13 is not working

Tags: android, flutter, user-permissions

In my flutter project, I need the device storage permission for downloading pdf. But in Android 13, in app permission settings, storage permission is not appearing.

I have used these permissions in
`..android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` which is given below.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="33" />
 <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="33" />
```

And here is the code to take the user permission

```
Future<bool> requestStoragePermission(Permission permission) async {
    AndroidDeviceInfo deviceInfo = await DeviceInfoPlugin().androidInfo;
    if (deviceInfo.version.sdkInt >= 30) {
      var status = 
          await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request().isGranted;
      if (!status) {
        await openAppSettings();
      }
      return status;
    } else {
      if (await permission.isGranted) {
        return true;
      } else {
        var status = await permission.request();
        return status.isGranted;
      }
    }
  }
```

It's not working showing *`Permission is denied`* message and debug result `No permissions found in manifest for: []22`

Comment: This might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72948052/android-13-read-external-storage-permission-still-usable and this https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storage Permission in Android 13 - Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75298807/storage-permission-in-android-13-flutter)

Comment: @Nguyenfamily no.

Comment: `need the device storage permission for downloading pdf. ` No. You do not need a storage permission to download a file.

Comment: `Permission.manageExternalStorage.request()` That has nothing to do with the permissions you mentioned in your manifest.

Comment: Working with PDFs, I wouldn't try to write to the external storage. You can access the [app specific storage without any permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific#internal). If you save the PDF in question to your app specific storage, you can then [open the PDF per intent](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/show-pdf-using-intent-in-android/) and let the user view the PDF in their application (default is Google Drive) which lets the user save, share, convert, etc the PDF itself, basically taking care of everything for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe when you are targeting **Android 13 or above**, you need to obtain access to Media Files Permission instead of `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

When you app runs in Android 13 devices, the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission mentioned in the Android Manifest will be ignored as mentioned in this article. Instead there are three new permissions were introduced starting Android 13.

> 1. READ_MEDIA_IMAGES
> 2. READ_MEDIA_VIDEO
> 3. READ_MEDIA_AUDIO.

If you were using `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` for accessing files, then you need to use one of these new permissions for Android 13 and above.

I would suggest you to get the more insights from the following [article](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions).

Similarly for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. You may check with the following [article from Android](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage) which clearly explains about permission related to storage

Hope this gives you broader picture about the Android Permission Model.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                requestPermissionWriteExternalStorage.launch(
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                )
            } else {
                requestPermissionWriteExternalStorage.launch(
                    Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES
                )
            }
```

Comment: A READ permission is no alternative for a WRITE permission. Your code makes no sense.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 1):

**You need to give permission in android manifest like this:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO"/>
```

**And for your flutter code**

```
Future<void> requestPermissionAndroid13() async {
    final permission1 = Permission.photos;
    if (await permission3.isDenied) {
      await permission1.request();
    }
  }
```