# Android 13 give permission issue after updating internal beta testing to the playstore(In production) app

Tags: android, permissions

-Granted READ_MEDIA_IMAGES permission

-Works *Good* if i only install the beta version **instead of updating playstore version**

I use it to retrive the image in DCIM folder, i gets the image path,size,name but image is not loaded

Comment: Well, what are the differences between the two versions of the app?

Comment: Internal beta test version is  only one version....if my device have no app of that kind the beta works perfectly.... but if I install previously release version app (in production) and update it with current version  then issue Aries