# Facing permission issues when we try to upload the image/file from the Android mobile app

Tags: react-native, sdk, android-permissions, android-api-levels

**Issue Description**:Our app points to API level/Sdk 33 with React Native version "0.59.0".
We are getting an issue when we click on the image icon to upload the image/file from mobile. We are using NativeModules.ImageCropPicker from "import {NativeModules} from 'react-native'" to upload the image/files.
Please find the attached error that will appear in the console.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8cnO.png)

**The solution we tried:**
We have added below permission in AndroidMainfest.xml

- READ_MEDIA_IMAGES: 'android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES'
- READ_MEDIA_VIDEO: 'android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO'
- READ_MEDIA_AUDIO: 'android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO'
  to access the image from the mobile, as these are permission's mentioned in https://reactnative.dev/docs/permissionsandroid.

Expecting:After adding the above permission its should work,but we are still getting Required permission missing.

Please let us know how we can fix this.

Comment: I'd recommend you to upgrade your react-native version as "0.59.0" is really old, it was released on March 12, 2019.

Comment: I had a similar problem recently, maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72948052/android-13-read-external-storage-permission-still-usable